# JPA/Hibernate "Composite-id class does not override equals()"

Tags: java, jpa

I'm using JPA and getting the following warning. I've researched this, and understand why I need to override it and how Hibernate uses these methods.  I still have a question though:

**Exception:**

> Composite-id class does not override equals()

**Question:**

Why does Hibernate only care about classes that don't have composite IDs? Does it by default compare on the `@Id` field if there is only one present, or is there something more complex going on here?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Because when entities don't have a composite ID, they have a single one, of one of the basic supported types (Integer, Long, String, etc.), and those classes already have a well-defined `equals()` (and `hashCode()`) method.

Comment: So, do I need to make a primary key class, or is it okay to just have 2 @Id scalar fields in the class and override equals there?

Comment: You should avoid composite keys. That's what you should really do. If you really can't because you target an existing schema that can't change, then you should define an PK class, yes.

Comment: Cool thanks, I'll accept this.  But one last question anyway... how do you avoid them in a normal many-to-many denormalization scenario where you need a table that just consists of 2 foreign keys?  You can let there be a third auto-generated key as the primary key, but then that key ends up being different in different data centers which is a nuisance and complicates debugging greatly.

Comment: If you have a many-to-many association between two tables, using a join table, then you should have a ManyToMany association between the entities. No need to map the join table. The association deals with it. Read the documentation.

Comment: Whoops, you're right.  I was already using a join table, I just created every database entity before I started working.  It turns out the entity reporting the error wasn't even used anywhere in the Java code.  Thanks man.

Comment: Use Lombok @EqualsAndHashCode on your composite ID class to generate them for you.

Answer (score 11):

Using JPA when you use composite key, you should use either `IdClass` or `EmbeddedId` using any of them you need to create an own class that act as a composite key, in order to be able to compare objects using this composite key which is required by several operations within the `EntityManager` that key classes must to override `equals` and `hashCode`.

Taking from specs:

> A composite primary key must correspond to either a single persistent field or property or to a set of such fields or properties as described below. A primary key class must be defined to represent a composite primary key. Composite primary keys typically arise when mapping from legacy databases when the database key is comprised of several columns. The `EmbeddedId` or `IdClass` annotation is used to denote a composite primary key.

And when using composite primary keys must follow.

1. The primary key class must be public and must have a public no-arg constructor.
2. The primary key class must be serializable.
3. The primary key class must define `equals` and `hashCode` methods. The semantics of value equality for these methods must be consistent with the database equality for the database types to which the key is mapped.

Comment: So, I cannot have a class with multiple @Id columns and just override equals there?