# Do I need to override equals() and hashCode() in the IdClass (composed key) of a jpa Entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

If I have a composed key in a Jpa Entity (MyEntity), do I need to add equals() and hashCode() in the IdClass (ID in this case)? It is considered as a duplication? or in the MyEntity "equals and hashCode()", I have to call those of ID class [return new MyEntity.ID(id1,id2).hashCode(); in the hashCode() of MyEntity] ?

```
@Entity
@IdClass(MyEntity.ID.class)
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    private long id1;
    @Id
    private long id2;

    private String otherField;
    public static class ID implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private long id1;
        private long id2;
        public ID() {
            super();
        }
        public ID(long id1, long id2) {
            super();
            this.id1 = id1;
            this.id2 = id2;
        }
        public long getId1() {
            return id1;
        }
        public void setId1(long id1) {
            this.id1 = id1;
        }
        public long getId2() {
            return id2;
        }
        public void setId2(long id2) {
            this.id2 = id2;
        }
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + (int) (id1 ^ (id1 >>> 32));
            result = prime * result + (int) (id2 ^ (id2 >>> 32));
            return result;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj) {
                return true;
            }
            if (obj == null) {
                return false;
            }
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
                return false;
            }
            ID other = (ID) obj;
            if (id1 != other.id1) {
                return false;
            }
            if (id2 != other.id2) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    public MyEntity() {
        super();
    }
    public long getId1() {
        return id1;
    }
    public void setId1(long id1) {
        this.id1 = id1;
    }
    public long getId2() {
        return id2;
    }
    public void setId2(long id2) {
        this.id2 = id2;
    }
    public String getOtherField() {
        return otherField;
    }
    public void setOtherField(String otherField) {
        this.otherField = otherField;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + (int) (id1 ^ (id1 >>> 32));
        result = prime * result + (int) (id2 ^ (id2 >>> 32));
        result = prime * result + ((otherField == null) ? 0 : otherField.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        MyEntity other = (MyEntity) obj;
        if (id1 != other.id1) {
            return false;
        }
        if (id2 != other.id2) {
            return false;
        }
        if (otherField == null) {
            if (other.otherField != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!otherField.equals(other.otherField)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: i'd say in both classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.

> do I need to add equals() and hashCode() in the IdClass (ID in this case)?

Yes, you do need it. Here is [the documentation](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Entities/Ids/IdClass):

> A composite primary key class has the following characteristics:
>
> ...
>
> - It defines equals and hashCode methods. The semantics of value equality for these methods must be consistent with the database equality for the database types to which the key is mapped.
>
> ...

2.

> or in the MyEntity "equals and hashCode()", I have to call those of ID class [return new MyEntity.ID(id1,id2).hashCode(); in the hashCode() of MyEntity] ?

I'm not sure what you actually mean, but you don't need to construct new instances of ID class. Just follow equals & hasCode contract rules from [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-). (autogenerating equals and hasCode in your IDE would also work just fine).

Answer (score 3):

Please have a look at this question [JPA/Hibernate “Composite-id class does not override equals()”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646456/jpa-hibernate-composite-id-class-does-not-override-equals)

Here are some items from the documentation regarding [equals() and hashCode()](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-model-pojo-equalshashcode)

> We recommend implementing `equals()` and `hashCode()` using **Business key
>   equality**. Business key equality means that the `equals()` method
>   compares only the properties that form the business key, a key that
>   would identify our instance in the real world (a **natural** candidate
>   key)

The question of equals/hashCode is not trivial, nor is there a one-size-fits-all solution.

> Although using a natural-id is best for equals and hashCode, sometimes
>   you only have the entity identifier that provides a unique constraint.
>
> It’s possible to use the entity identifier for equality check, but it
>   needs a workaround:
>
> you need to provide a constant value for hashCode so that the hash
>   code value does not change before and after the entity is flushed.
>
> you need to compare the entity identifier equality only for
>   non-transient entities.

Also a good article [EqualsandHashCode](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/EqualsandHashCode)