# javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, exception, sequence

Previously i was not getting any error but suddenly i am started getting error :

```
javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [baag.betl.dbimporter.esmatrans.db.EquSecurityReferenceData#baag.db.SECU@59c70ceb]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:116) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:155) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:787) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:765) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
```

There is no sequence created for any column in oracle database table. Also there is combination of unique key column for esn and techid. I dont want to create new sequence column in my database table.

I think i cannot use  @GeneratedValue and set it to Auto for unique columns otherwise i will get hibernate sequence error.

I am also doing clear and flush after every 1000 records processed.

```
if (secuData != null) {
                sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(secuData);
}

i++;
    if (i % 1000 == 0) {
                sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();
                sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().clear();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have a composite primary key, you can either have the use of `@IdClass` or `@Embeddable` key approach.

To continue with the `@IdClass` approach you need to follow some rules,

- The composite primary key class must be public
- It must have a no-arg constructor
- It must define equals() and hashCode() methods
- It must be Serializable

So in your case, the class would look like,

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "SECU" )
@IdClass( SECU.class )
public class SECU implements Serializable
{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "columnName") // use the correct column name if it varies from the variable name provided
    protected String esn;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "columnName") // use the correct column name if it varies from the variable name provided
    protected BigDecimal techrcrdid;

    @Column(name = "columnName") // use the correct column name if it varies from the variable name provided
    protected BigDecimal preTradLrgInScaleThrshld;

    @Column(name = "columnName") // use the correct column name if it varies from the variable name provided
    @Temporal( TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    protected LocalDateTime CreDt;

    @Column(name = "columnName") // use the correct column name if it varies from the variable name provided
    protected String fullnm;

    @Override
    public boolean equals( Object o )
    {
        if( this == o ) return true;
        if( !( o instanceof SECU ) ) return false;
        SECU secu = ( SECU ) o;
        return Objects.equals( esn, secu.esn ) &&
                       Objects.equals( techrcrdid, secu.techrcrdid ) &&
                       Objects.equals( preTradLrgInScaleThrshld, secu.preTradLrgInScaleThrshld ) &&
                       Objects.equals( CreDt, secu.CreDt ) &&
                       Objects.equals( fullnm, secu.fullnm );
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return Objects.hash( esn, techrcrdid, preTradLrgInScaleThrshld, CreDt, fullnm );
    }

    // getters and setters 
}
```

Also double check your getters and setters in each entity class, the once provided in your question seems incorrect.

Comment: its working fine :) but i just need to know what does equals() and hashCode() methods do here to solve the issue?

Comment: @Andrew If this helped, please mark the answer as accepted. For your question here, you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646456/jpa-hibernate-composite-id-class-does-not-override-equals and I quote, "when the primary key is not a composite key, they are usually of the basic supported types of `Integer, Long, String` and their `equals` and `hashcode` methods are well defined."

Answer (score 1):

Your entity class appears to be modelling a composite primary key, but I only see 2 `@Id` and no `@IdClass` annotation used which is necessary.

Comment: yes its combination of primary key but where do i need @IdClass exactly ?

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13032948/how-to-create-and-handle-composite-primary-key-in-jpa

Comment: i tried to create @IdClass(Secu.class) but still gives same error