# How should I override equals/hashCode in entities with composite primary keys?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, equals, hashcode, composite-primary-key

I have a table with a composite primary keys including it's own and a FK from other table.

I decided not to use an `@IdClass` nor `@EmbeddedId`.

```java
class SomeEntity {

    @Id
    private String someId;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = ...)
    private Other other

    // other mappings here
}
```

And Hibernate warns these.

```
WARN 69752 ... : HHH000038: Composite-id class does not override equals(): ....Some
WARN 69752 ... : HHH000039: Composite-id class does not override hashCode(): ....Some
```

How can(should) I implement these two methods?

Can(should) I include only these two fields? What about other fields?

```java
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Some that = (Some) o;
        return Objects.equals(someId, that.someId) &&
                Objects.equals(other, that.other);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(someId, other);
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JPA/Hibernate "Composite-id class does not override equals()"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646456/jpa-hibernate-composite-id-class-does-not-override-equals)

Comment: @SternK Thanks for the link. It's about the same context, unfortunately, not the same case, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I decided not to use an `@IdClass` nor `@EmbeddedId`.

I have to say that this decision has two drawbacks:

1. This approach is not allowed by JPA specification, so it is hibernate specific solution. (See [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-composite))
2. There’s no separation between the entity instance and the actual identifier. To query this entity, an instance of the entity itself must be supplied to the persistence context. (See [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-composite-associations))

Imagine, you have the following entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "TST_FIRST_ENTITY_EHC")
public class FirstEntity implements Serializable 
{
   @Id
   @Column(name = "fst_id")
   private Long id;
   
   @NaturalId
   @Column(name = "fst_code")
   private String code;
   
   @Id
   @ManyToOne(optional = false)
   @JoinColumn(name = "fst_sec_id")
   private SecondEntity secondEntity;
   
   public FirstEntity()
   {
   }
   
   public FirstEntity(Long id, Long secId)
   {
      this.id = id;
      secondEntity = new SecondEntity();
      secondEntity.setId(secId);
   }
   // ...
}
```

To find this entity by PK you should write something like this:

```java
FirstEntity item = session.find(FirstEntity.class, new FirstEntity(1L, 2L));
```

As for me, it looks quite awkward.

As for your main question, you can use any set of fields that identify your entity.
Imagine, that for the above entity you have the following DDL SQL:

```sql
create table TST_FIRST_ENTITY_EHC
(
   fst_id bigint,
   fst_sec_id bigint,
   fst_code varchar(25),
   fst_value varchar(500),
   
   primary key (fst_id, fst_sec_id),
   unique(fst_code),
   foreign key (fst_sec_id) REFERENCES TST_SECOND_ENTITY_EHC(sec_id)
);
```

You can implement `equals` and `hashCode` of your entity based on the `id`, `secondEntity.id` fields or based on the `code` field. The approach based on the natural-id or business-key is preferable because if you use database id generation you can not know the actual id values before the JPA transaction is committed. (See [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-model-pojo-equalshashcode)).